# Apple LLVM Error after trying to add google sign in

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-signin

I tried following this example to the tee: 
[Swift iOS Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start?ver=swift)

And even tried the `pod try Google` demo app but that doesn't even go past the splash screen before a SIGABRT.

I'm sure I am still doing something wrong but I can't figure out what it would be. I have added the bridging-header file as it suggested and when I command click on any GID referenced file it links me back to the source. I haven't fully connected up the UI components but I am assuming it should still be able to `Build Succeed` and launch the app empty nonetheless.

I have isolated it down to just the cocoa pod installation of Google related items. Even after adding the generated file `GoogleService-Info.plist` from the instructions to all targets and at the root of my XCode project I still get the same error:

`clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files`

When I remove Google items from the Podfile it seems to run fine. I still have Alamofire, SwiftyJSON there so the pods are installing and being referenced just fine. I also have Facebook login working perfectly also! Just can't seem to figure out what's going wrong here...

The full error is again:

`Apple LLVM 6.1 Error: clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files`